# Creating a for loop that will echo a range of numbers in increments of 1

Tags: php, for-loop

Based on the output of the following, I was wondering if anyone could assist me:

```
  $monthsOfTheYear = range(1, 12);
  print_r ($monthsOfTheYear);
```

I understand the above process, but what would be the most effective method to recreate this principle with a for loop? I've come up with the following so far:

```
  $months = ("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", September", "October", "November", "December") {

  for($months{0} = 1, $months{11} = 12, /*????*/) {
      echo "/*????*/";
  } }
```

If possible I'd like to know how to achieve this within the code for the loop, though I suspect it may require a more complex solution.

Comment: It's sad that you've ended with code, which is incorrect even in syntax. I suggest to read about [for loops](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) in PHP.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want to print month's names?

Comment: StackOverflow is not your lint checker, please don't treat it as so.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough, I want to achieve an output of the numbers 1 to 12, with each number representing its corresponding month. Thanks Alma.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to do this.?May be but i am not sure if you want this.Please make your question a little bit more clear.Try adding a sample output.

```
$months = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
for($i = 0;$i < 12; $i++){
 echo $months[$i].'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 12; $i++) {
    echo $monthsOfTheYear[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the dozens of possible solutions is

```
foreach(array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December") as $month) {
    echo $month . "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
$months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

for ($i=0; $i<count($months); $i++) {
  echo "$months[$i]\n";
}
```

See the output at http://3v4l.org/T740C